# Is there a way to connect the Selberg Integral to a Cornu Spiral

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis

I want to find a connection between the Selberg Integral and a Cornu Spiral.

Is there some sort of geometric connection between them.

Given the Selberg Integral:

$$S_n (\alpha, \beta, \gamma) = \int_{0}^{1} \dots \int_{0}^{1} \prod_{i=1}^n t_i^{\alpha-1}(1-t_i)^{\beta-1} \prod_{1 \leq i < j \leq n} \lvert t_i - t_j \rvert^{2\gamma} \: dt_1 \dots dt_n$$

and cornu spirals:

$$S(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \cos(t^2) dt$$
$$C(x) = \int_{0}^{x} \sin(t^2) dt$$

Any input would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe these things are related? The Cornu spirals are defined by integrals that are (incomplete) gamma functions, and the Selberg integrals are generalized beta functions. These two objects are related by $B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ but this is rather tenuous since those are complete gamma functions. Although I admit I don't know a lot about special functions, I don't really see where you want these two things to contact.